# JFreeChart axis position

Tags: position, jfreechart

Assume a common bar chart with a vertical axis on the left ... I wonder how could I control the space between the left side of the chart and the vertical axis? The idea is that whenever the tick labels displayed on the axis get bigger, the axis is pushed to the right to accommodate the tick labels. I want to be able to specify that the axis should be always displayed at 20% of the entire width of the chart, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

A bar chart typically has a [`CategoryAxis`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/CategoryAxis.html) for the domain, so you might experiment with `setLowerMargin()`, `setUpperMargin()` and `setCategoryMargin()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a fixed axis space on the range axis:
http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/gjdoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/XYPlot.html#setFixedRangeAxisSpace:AxisSpace

Assuming you are just creating a chart image:

```
// Get your plot from the chart object..
XYPlot plot = (XYPlot)chart.getPlot();

// Create an instance of the image so we can do some calculations
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage( width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

// Create an instance of the Graphics2D from your image
Graphics2D g2 = image.createGraphics();

// Get the reserve space that jfree chart sets aside for the axis
AxisSpace space = yAxis.reserveSpace(g2, plot, new Rectangle(width,height), plot.getRangeAxisEdge(), plot.getFixedRangeAxisSpace());

// Give that space a fixed width
space.setLeft(fixedAxisWidth);

// Set it in the plot
plot.setFixedRangeAxisSpace(space);
```

You might be able to just define an AxisSpace without going through all the Graphics2D rigamarole, but this is how I've done it in the past.